# Swift optional assignment, deal with nil/empty string

Tags: swift, struct, option-type

I'm trying to solve an string assignment problem in Swift:
Here we have a struct:

```
struct Student {
    var name: String
    var id: String
    var mentor: String?
    var grade: String?
}
```

And we want to parse it into a string, something like:

```
if (mentor != nil && grade != nil) {
    return "Student info: name:" + name + " id:" + id + " mentor:" + mentor! + " grade:" + grade! + "."
} else if (mentor != nil) {
    return "Student info: name:" + name + " id:" + id + " mentor:" + mentor! + "."
} else if (grade != nil) { 
    return "Student info: name:" + name + " id:" + id + " grade:" + grade! + "."
} else {
    return "Student info: name:" + name + " id:" + id + "."
}
```

I'm new to the Swift, the code above is based on other language's experience, I'm wondering if there's any more concise way to achieve that in Swift? Like deal with optional toString(), if it's nil then return a empty string ""?

Comment: This belongs on codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Anytime you find yourself writing `if x != nil { use(x!) }`, use conditional binding instead: `if let x = x { use(x) }`

Comment: What is the difference between having a mentor of `nil` and having a mentor of `""`? If "empty mentor" is the same as "no mentor" then I recommend making mentor a normal String, and testing `isEmpty` rather than for `nil`. It dramatically simplifies usage throughout the system if you avoid unnecessary optionals.

Comment: @RobNapier For once, I actually disagree with you. Being able to nil coalesce to provide a default value (e.g. "No mentor") is a convenience you can't get when checking for an empty empty string

Comment: @Alexander This is only valuable if you would *not* want to do that for an empty string. If you would want the empty string to be actually empty, and `nil` to be "No mentor", then you're right; they're different and should have different values. But if you have to check for `isEmptyOrNil` to print "No mentor," then the value of nil coalescing goes away. The important thing is the meaning of the data first, and then what syntax works nicest for that. Never put syntax first. (I can easily create an `isEmpty`-coalescing operator if that were a big problem anyway.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alexander's answer is good, and makes good use of the higher order function map(), but it might be a bit over your head if you're just starting out. You could simplify your code quite a bit with judicious use of `if let` "optional binding":

```
var result = "Student info: name:" + name + " id:" + id
if let mentor = mentor {
  result += " mentor:" + mentor
}
if let grade = grade {
  result += " grade:" + grade
}
result += "."

return result
```

Or rewritten to avoid the `+` operator:

```
var result = "Student info: name:\(name) id:\(id)"
if let mentor = mentor {
  result.append(" mentor:\(mentor)")
}
if let grade = grade {
  result.append(" grade:\(grade)")
}
result.append(".")

return result
```

Comment: I'm still using the "+" operator, but I decided to prefer clarity over efficiency for the purposes of a forum post.

Comment: That's reasonable, and the compile time cost of `+` isn't an issue when there is only one or two of them in an expression. The type checker is factorial over the number of expressions, so it just gets really bad very quickly thereafter

Comment: Compile-time performance is `O(n!)` for the number of `+` operators in a single expression? Wow. That's awful if n gets bigger than a handful.

Comment: Yep. The type-checker is essentially solving a maze. It knows the start point (the types of the operands) and sometimes knows the end point (the expected result type of the expression), and has to navigate from start to end, picking the right operands to make a cohesive path.

Comment: Notice that a maze is easier when you work forward from the start and backwards from the end, with the hope of finding a point midway where two halves meet. This is faster because (if you take `n` to be the number of "junctions" and `a` to be average number of choices at each junction) `a^n + a^n = 2a^n`, which is much much less than than `a^2n`. Interestingly, the same thing applies here. Merely specifying the expected result of an expression (e.g. with a type annotation) will *significantly* speed up the type checking.

Comment: The compile time speed of this is made even worse when you consider that each `"quoted string"` is actually a String literal, which can be interpreted as any one of the `ExpressibleByStringLiteral` types. That adds even more possibilities for the type checker to contend with

Answer (score 1):

Here are the improvements I would make:

Firstly, you should remove the unnecessary parentheses around the `if` predicates. You may be used to them from other C-like languages, but in Swift they're just noise.

Secondly, you should replace string concatenation (`+`) with interpolation. It has much faster compile times (operator type inference slows the compiler substantially), and will soon (with the rework of string interpolation) have better runtime performance (no redundant string allocation).

Next, I would use `Optional.map` to construct all the parts of the sentence that are optional. Then, I would default them to the empty string, if they're `nil`.

Then, I would take all the segments of the string, and join them together with a space as a separator:

```
struct Student {
    var name: String
    var id: String
    var mentor: String?
    var grade: String?
}

extension Student: CustomStringConvertible {
    var description: String {
        let start = "Student info:"
        let nameSegment = "name: \(self.name)"
        let idSegment = "id: \(self.id)"
        let mentorSegment = self.mentor.map { "mentor: \($0)" } ?? ""
        let gradeSegment = self.grade.map { "grade: \($0)" } ?? ""
        return [start, nameSegment, idSegment, mentorSegment, gradeSegment].joined(separator: " ")
    }
}

print(Student(name: "Bob", id: "id123", mentor: "Mr. Mentor", grade: "123"))
// => Student info: name: Bob id: id123 mentor: Mr. Mentor grade: 123
```